# BatchWrite in AWS dynamo db skipping some items

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write Items to AWS dynamo db using node SDK. The problem I am facing is that when I write batch items to AWS in **parallel** using threads, some of the items are not written to database. The number of items are written are random. For instance, If I run my code 3 times, at one time it would be 150, next it would 200 and third time it could be 135. In addition, when I write the items sequentially without threads, even then some of the items are not written.However, in this case the items are less missing. For instance if the total number of items is 300 then the items written are 298.  I investigated the problem to see if there any unprocessed items but the batchWrite method returns nothing. It means that all the items are being processed correctly. Please note that I have ***OnDemand provision*** for my respective database so I do not expect any throttling issues. So here is my code.

```
 exports.run = async function() {

  **This is the function which runs first !!!!!**

  const data = await getArrayOfObjects();
  console.log("TOTAL PRICE CHANGES")  
  console.log(data.length)
  const batchesOfData = makeBatches(data)
  const threads = new Set();
  console.log("**********")
  console.log(batchesOfData.length)
  console.log("**********")
  for(let i = 0; i < batchesOfData.length; i++) {
    console.log("BATCH!!!!!")
    console.log(i)
    console.log(batchesOfData[i].length)  
    // Sequential Approach
    const response = await compensationHelper.createItems(batchesOfData[i])
    console.log("RESPONSE")
    console.log(response)

    Parallel approach
    // const workerResult = await runService(batchesOfData[i])
    // console.log("WORKER RESUULT!!!!")
    // console.log(workerResult);

  }
}

exports.updateItemsInBatch = async function(data, tableName) {
  console.log("WRITING DATA")
  console.log(data.length)
  const batchItems = {
    RequestItems: {},
  };

  batchItems.RequestItems[tableName] = data;
  try {
    const result = await documentClient.batchWrite(batchItems).promise();
    console.log("UNPROCESSED ITEMS")
    console.log(result)
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      console.log(`[Error]: ${JSON.stringify(Error)}`);
      throw new Error(result);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`[Error]: ${JSON.stringify(err.message)}`);
    return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
  }
};

exports.convertToAWSCompatibleFormat = function(data) {
  const awsCompatibleData = [];
  data.forEach(record => awsCompatibleData.push({ PutRequest: { Item: record } }));
  return awsCompatibleData;
};

const createItems = async function(itemList) {
  try {
    const objectsList = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < itemList.length; index++) {
      try {
        const itemListObj = itemList[index];
        const ObjToBeInserted = {
          // some data assignments here
        };

        objectsList.push(ObjToBeInserted);
        if (
          objectsList.length >= AWS_BATCH_SIZE ||
          index === itemList.length - 1
        ) {
            const awsCompatiableFormat = convertToAWSCompatibleFormat(
              objectsList
            );
            await updateItemsInBatch(
              awsCompatiableFormat,
              process.env.myTableName
            );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`[Error]: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
      }
    }

    return Promise.resolve(true);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
  }
};

const makeBatches = products => {
  const productBatches = [];
  let countr = -1;
  for (let index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
    if (index % AWS_BATCH_SIZE === 0) {
      countr++;
      productBatches[countr] = [];
      if (countr === MAX_BATCHES) {
        break;
      }
    }
    try {
      productBatches[countr].push(products[index]);
    } catch (error) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return productBatches;
};

async function runService(workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, './worker.js'), { workerData });
    worker.on('message', resolve);
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
    })
  })
}

// My worker file
'use strict';

const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads')
const creatItems = require('myscripts')
// You can do any heavy stuff here, in a synchronous way
// without blocking the "main thread"
console.log("I AM A NEW THREAD")
createItems(workerData)
// console.log('Going to write tons of content on file '+workerData);
parentPort.postMessage({ fileName: workerData, status: 'Done' })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had duplicate keys issue which means that primary and the sort key had duplicate values in the batch, however, in my case this error was not returned from the AWS BatchWrite method if my timestamp was in fraction of seconds `2020-02-09T08:02:36.71`, which was a bit surprising. I resolved the issue by making my createdAt(sort key) to be more granular like this => `2020-02-09T08:02:36.7187` Thus making it non-repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

From [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item):

> If one or more of the following is true, DynamoDB rejects the entire batch write operation:

```
One or more tables specified in the BatchWriteItem request does not exist.
Primary key attributes specified on an item in the request do not match those in the corresponding table's primary key schema.
You try to perform multiple operations on the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request. For example, you cannot put and delete the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request.
Your request contains at least two items with identical hash and range keys (which essentially is two put operations).
There are more than 25 requests in the batch.
Any individual item in a batch exceeds 400 KB.
The total request size exceeds 16 MB.
```

To me, it looks some of this is true. At my job, we also had a problem that one batch contained 2 identical primary and secondary keys in the batch so the whole batch was discarded. I know it's not node.js, but we used [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.batch_writer) to overcome that problem.

It is `batch_writer(overwrite_by_pkeys)` and it is used to overwrite the last occurance of the same primary and last key in the batch. If only a small portion of your data is duplicate data and you do not need to save it, you can use this. BUT if you need to save all your data, I do not advise you to use this functionality.

Comment: The problem is that there is no errors return by the updateItemsInBatch method. If I assume my batch breaks one of these conditions then it would return some errors. But this is not the case. IF I deliberately add duplicate keys then it returns me the error but for now I get no error :(.

Comment: there is also one thing to notice, when i send the requests in serial fashion , then if my entire batch is discarded then the number should drop by 25 but this is not the case, only 2 are being dropped.

Comment: Just for the sake, my sort key is createdAt which is `2020-02-09T08:02:36.71` It means the chances of being this as duplicate is quite less since it goes in the fraction of a second. I have not yet faced any duplicate keys issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are checking the response for `UnprocessedItems`. Batch operations will often return a list of items it didn't process. As is documented,  [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) "can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests."

Comment: I am checking the response in updateItemsInBatch method.

Comment: There is also try and catch in case I get some error then it would print the error on the console. but currently, I get no error printed.

Comment: You’re checking for an error, but UnprocessedItems will be populated when there is no error.

Comment: I actually print them as well but there is no list for the unprocessed items.