# AWS DynamoDB batchWriteItem in Lamda is not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have an app created via AWS Amplify and I created an AWS Lambda function that aim to insert multiple data to one of the table in DynamoDB.

Firstly, I tried map attributes to `documentClient.put({...params}).promise()` and run `Promise.all()` on it. But some items got lost. For example, I add 40 items at once, but only 5-10 got added. I thought this could be some lambda limit issue. So I switch to `batchWriteItem()` and seems it remain the same or even worse (only 1 out of 40 got added). Here is the code I wrote:

```js
export const addAvailabilities = async (
  docClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient,
  newAvailabilities: Availability[],
  expertId: string,
  cognitoUserId: string
) => {
  console.info('#addAvailabilities: Start')
  try {
    let restArray = [...newAvailabilities]
    const promiseArray = []
    while (restArray.length > 0) {
      const executingArray = restArray.slice(0, 25)
      const temp = batchAddAvailability(docClient, executingArray, expertId, cognitoUserId)
      promiseArray.push(temp)
      restArray = restArray.slice(25)
    }
    const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray)
    console.info(result)
    console.info('#addAvailabilities: End')
    return result
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('#addAvailabilities: Error')
    throw err
  }
}

const mapBatchAddAvailabilityParams = (newAvailabilities: Availability[], expertId: string, cognitoUserId: string) => {
  return newAvailabilities.map((availability, index) => {
    const currentTime = `${moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SS')}${index}Z`
    return {
      PutRequest: {
        Item: {
          id: uuid(),
          __typename: 'ExpertAvailability',
          expertId: expertId,
          owner: cognitoUserId,
          startTime: availability.start,
          status: 'available',
          createdAt: currentTime,
          updatedAt: currentTime
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
const batchAddAvailability = async (
  docClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient,
  newAvailabilities: Availability[],
  expertId: string,
  cognitoUserId: string
) => {
  console.info('#batchAddAvailability: Start')
  try {
    const batchParams = mapBatchAddAvailabilityParams(newAvailabilities, expertId, cognitoUserId)
    const param = {
      RequestItems: {
        [process.env.API_TAP_EXPERTAVAILABILITYTABLE_NAME]: batchParams
      }
    }
    console.info('params', JSON.stringify(param))
    return docClient.batchWrite(param).promise()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('#batchAddAvailability: Error')
    throw err
  }
}
```

I add this `const currentTime =` ${moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SS')}${index}Z` because I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223144/2718622) has similar issue as mine and that's the solution solve his problem. But it doesn't solve mine.

From the logs, `params` get format correctly like this:

```js
{
    "RequestItems": {
        "Availability": [
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "66a7b63e-a14b-4ba2-94a9-0dd7bf457efe",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-03T23:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.880Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.880Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "162d839d-7fde-417e-994b-2dc12336c4cf",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.881Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.881Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "dc257c75-9a27-482a-88c5-1747ffe97361",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-04T01:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.932Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.932Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "75b2e911-e842-4f11-99ed-702c6cf1c485",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-04T02:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.943Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.943Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "df65e151-1699-446d-ab3b-06aca707a2fb",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-04T03:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.944Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.944Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "id": "98a5bdd2-60d3-4d5d-9913-40b5c84c6d62",
                        "__typename": "ExpertAvailability",
                        "expertId": "8d30c1a4-685e-40bf-b884-6e50bb422e99",
                        "owner": "test-keycloak_eeb71cb1-6c11-4fb9-a721-ce5dc7d06269",
                        "startTime": "2021-10-04T04:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "available",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.945Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-08T10:24:28.945Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There is no `UnprocessedItems` or any errors return from the execution. But the items are just missing. The capacity of the table is **on-demand** so I think capacity shouldn't be a problem. Any ideas what's wrong? Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are awaiting all your promises? Can you show more code? How do you call `addAvailabilities`

Comment: Just simply call it like this `await addAvailabilities(docClient, newAvailabilities, expertProfile.id, requestSender)`. `newAvailabilities` is an array of string (UTC ISO string)

Comment: What is the table's partition and sort key?

Comment: The primary key is `id`. And as this table is created by AWS Amplify. I think there is no sort key got created in the process (I can't find it in the generated cloudformation template).

Comment: How do you know the records are not in the table?

Comment: I can't find them in the table from DynamoDB console. The other thing I found is that I have another environment has exactly same setup (created by AWS Amplify) has no this issue.

Comment: Did you do a query or just look at the results of the scan? Note that scan results are only ordered by page, not across the whole table.

Comment: I think you are right, it's my mistake. I didn't realise that the data will get sorted by `id` without `sort key` for the table. Then the GraphQL will only return first 100 items by default. Same thing happened on DynamoDB console. It only shows first 100 itmes and if you click on sort by a specific attribute, it only sort that first 100 items instead of every items. And that's why I thought the data is not in. Now it's all solved. Thanks for you help.